# How long does a Cisco RV325 firmware update take?

Tags: cisco, router

I just bought this router.  All I've done so far is change the default password.  I threw the latest firmware on a USB stick, shoved that in the computer (there is other stuff on the USB stick, and I wasn't sure how the router would deal with it if I put it in the router's USB port), and pointed the firmware update tool at the file. I hit start/OK/whatever it said.  Well, that was a good 30-40 minutes ago, and it's just displaying a barbershop-like sideways progress bar, and the red diag light is flashing on the device.

Is this thing dead or do I have to keep waiting?  If it's dead, how do I fix it?  I can't seem to find any info about this online, and I haven't the faintest idea how to ask in Cisco's communities (just keeps telling me access denied when I try to create an account there).

Comment: Oh I forgot to add, before anyone asks:  I'm plugged in the first LAN port.  Nothing else is plugged into this router.  Obviously I'm using a different network to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah never mind.  I finally discovered how to actually log into their community site (it involves being on the actual main page of the community site and then clicking login from there, and not trying to click the "start discussion" link on the RV325 page).  I have to set the computer's IP address to 192.168.1.100.  And the fix to restarting this process is a hard reset (hold reset 10+ seconds).

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Comment: It wouldn't let me before but seems to be letting me now.

Comment: You accepted it!

Comment: Jeeze you're fast lol.  I think it wouldn't let me before with some error message of the sort that I had to wait some amount of time before I could accept.  So of course I forgot about it.